# How is a string represented in IA32 assembly?

Tags: c, assembly

A string is represented as an array of char. For example, if I have a string "abcdef" at address 0x80000000, is the following correct?

```
0x80000008
0x80000004: 00 00 46 45
0x80000000: 44 43 42 41
```

(In stack, it grows down so I have address decreasing)

Comment: Yes. But, instead of asking here, it would have been faster to check either by asking the assembler output of a C compiler (`gcc -Wall -fverbose-asm -O` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or by looking in the debugger (`gdb`)

Comment: That's not assembly, that's just a memory dump.

Comment: Hmm. So the address of 41 is 0x8000000? and the address of 44 would be 0x80000003?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The lower addresses are always first - even in the stack. So your example should be:

   ```
   80000000: 41 42 43 44 
   80000004: 45 46 00 00
   ```
2. Your example is actually the string: "ABCDEF". The string "abcdef" should be:

   ```
   80000000: 61 62 63 64
   80000004: 65 66 00 00
   ```

Also, in memory dumps, the default radix is 16 (hexadecimal), so "0x" is redundant. Notice that the character codes are also in hexadecimal. For example the string "JKLMNOP" will be:

```
   80000000: 4A 4B 4C 4D
   80000000: 4E 4F 50 00
```

3. No strings are usually placed in the stack. Only in data memory. Sometimes in the stack are placed pointers to strings, i.e. the start address of the string.
4. Your (and my) examples concerns so called [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding. But there are many possible [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) schemes possible. For example [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) also uses 8bit codes, but different than ASCII.

But the 8 bit codes are not mandatory. UTF-32 for example uses 32 bit codes. Also, it is not mandatory to have fixed code size. UTF-8 uses variable code size from 1 to 6 bytes, depending on the characters encoded.

Comment: In the stack convention, it grows downward (when push the address is subtracted), therefore higher address is on top. How should I think in this scenario?

Comment: And also stack is a part of memory right (virtual memory)?

Comment: 1. I always preferred to imagine that the memory has beginning (address 0) and end (address fffff...). The beginning is at the top of the screen/sheet/scroll and the end is at the bottom of it. The stack actually does not grow (well, it grows, but it is a side effect and not important). The stack top, moves backward - towards  lower addresses. And the stack start is at the bottom of the memory. :)  2. The stack is of course memory, but as a stack it has some special purpose and string data is usually not placed in the stack itself. (the local variables are special case for another talk).

Answer (score 0):

That isn’t actually assembly.  You can get an example of that by running `gcc-S`.  Traditionally in x86 assembly, you would declare a label followed by a string, which would be declared as `db` (data bytes).  If it were a C-style string, it would be followed by `db 0`.  Modern assemblers have an `asciiz` type that adds the zero byte automatically.  If it were a Pascsl-style string, it would be preceded by an integer containing its size.  These would be laid out contiguously in memory, and you would get the address of the string by using the label, similarly to how you would get the address of a branch target from its label.

Which option you would use depends on what you’re going to do with it.  If you’re passing to a C standard library function, you probably want a C-style string.  If you’re going to be writing it with `write()` or `send()` and copying it to buffers with bounds-checking, you might want to store its length explicitly, even though no system or library call uses that format any more.  Good, secure code shouldn’t use `strcpy()` either.  However, you can both store the length and null-terminate the string.

Some old code for MS-DOS used strings terminated with `$`, a convention copied from CP/M for compatibility with 8-bit code on the Z80.  There were a bunch of these legacies in OSes up to Windows ME.